# Simplify conditions in python

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

I need to check different elements of a a list with certain conditions, but the script it's really a pain to read, so I need something that can simplify this mess:

```
if element[0] != "]" and element[0] != "[" and element[0] != "*" and element[0] != "."element[0] != "," and element[0] != "-":
                tmp.append(element[0])
```

Is there a way to make it easier and with less conditions? I should also add other conditions.

Comment: `if element[0] not in [...]`?

Comment: Try to use https://github.com/wemake-services/wemake-python-styleguide It will tell you about problems in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `len(element[0]) < 2`, simply ask if the element is `not in` a string with the chars that you want to filter out:

```
if element[0] not in '][*.,-':
    tmp.append(element[0])
```

But, if `element[0]` has a length greater than one, then you should use a different approach:

```
if all(element[0] != c for c in '][*.,-'):
    tmp.append(element[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if not element[0] in ["]", "[", "*", ".", "," ,"-"]:
                ttmp.append(element[0])
```

OR

```
 if not element[0] in "][*.,-]":
                tmp.append(element[0])
```

Comment: Or just `if element[0] not in '[]*.,-'`:

Comment: PEP8 recommends `if element[0] not in`